# reading a file using a given class

Tags: java, file, file-io

I'm working on a program that basically is about reading lines of a file using (obligatory) this class:

```
public class Paraula {
// Public 

    public static final char blank = ' ';
    public static final char endSequence = '\n';
// Private
// Max length of a Paraula(Word)
    private static final int MAXIM = 20;

    public char[] letters;
    public int length;

    private static char letter= ' ';

    public static char[] phrase= null;
    public static int indice;



// Constructor

    public Paraula() {
        letters= new char[MAXIM];
        length= 0;
    }


//reading a word from an input sequence

    public static Paraula llegir() {
        Paraula nova = new Paraula();
        jumpBlanks();
        while ((letter!= endSequence) && // sequence has not reached end
                (letter!= blank)) { // there's enough space/room?
            nova.letters[nova.length++] = letter;
            letter= readCharKeyB();
        }

        return nova;
    }



// Convert Paraula into String
    public String toString() {
        String msg = "";
        for (int idx = 0; idx < length; idx++) {
            msg += letters[idx];
        }
        return msg;
    }


// comparing two objects Paraula

    public boolean esIgualA(Paraula b) {
        boolean iguals = letters== b.length;
        for (int idx = 0; (idx < length) && iguals; idx++) {
            iguals = letters[idx] == b.letters[idx];
        }
        return iguals;
    }


    public static boolean iguals(Paraula a, Paraula b) {
// using method above
        return a.esIgualA(b);
    }


// to determine if a Paraula is empty

    public boolean empty() {
        return length== 0;
    }


// reading the necessary until finding a Paraula
    public static void jumpBlanks() {
        while (letter== blanc) {
            letter= readCharKeyB();
        }
    }


//jump characters if the Paraula is too long

    public static void jumpWord() throws Exception {
        while ((letter != '.') && (letter!= blanc)) {
            letter= readCharKeyB();
        }
    }


    static public char readCharKeyB() {
        char res = '\n';
        if (phrase!= null) {
            res = phrase[indice++];
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Every line of the file I have to read looks like this:

0001 #n name of the person #d address

0002 ....

........

So I have to read the line and the pull out the name, the address and the code.
I have no idea how to do it, although I've been working on it for several days. 
Here's what I have. It's just something that reads one line of the file and print the Paraula objects contained in the line, but I don't know how to do it to extract things from the line to use them later. And I also don't know how to read the next line.

```
    private void inicio() throws Exception {
        lecturaFichero();
        parseLine(lecturaFichero());

        System.out.println("A partir de la base de datos de clientes de la empresa el programa se encargará de generar"
                + " cartas para cada uno de los clientes." + "\n");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        (new Práctica_Final()).inicio();

    }

    public static String lecturaFichero() throws Exception {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("datos_clientes.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String linea = br.readLine();

        br.close();
        fr.close();
        return linea;
    }

    private static void parseLine(String line) {
        char[] whatever = line.toCharArray();
        Paraula.phrase= whatever;
        Paraula w;
        int idx = 0;
        while (whatever[idx] != '\n') {
            w = Paraula.llegir();
            System.out.println(w);
            idx++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please translate your identifiers to english?

Comment: Hope you'll understand better! Paraula it's a word and llegir=read @TimoSta

Comment: I got confuse.You want to parse the file and keep only name and address , right?

Comment: Yes, and the code (0001 for example) . Using that class to do it @TsakiroglouFotis

Comment: The file is static??do you need to check the lines of the file??Why you have to use(obligatory) this class??Does this class do what you want, are you sure??

Comment: I have to check the lines because I need to extract things from them. And yes, it's obligatory, because it's for a project at university, and they gave us this class to do it @TsakiroglouFotis

Comment: ok give me 10 minutes I will send a short code that does the job.If it works I ll help you apply my code in your obligatory class.

Comment: ok thank you very much!! @TsakiroglouFotis

Comment: Do you have something already? @TsakiroglouFotis

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation that can parse your example input:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Parser {
    public class Line {
        private final int id;
        private final String name;
        private final String address;

        public Line(int id, String name, String address) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", address=" + address;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Parser parser = new Parser();
        parser.parse("path/to/file");
        parser.printLines();
    }

    private final List<Line> lines = new LinkedList<Line>();

    public void parse(String filename) throws IOException {
        Files.lines(Paths.get(filename), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                .forEachOrdered(this::parseLine);
    }

    private void parseLine(String line) {
        String[] idAndRest = line.split("\\s*#n\\s*", 2);
        int id = Integer.parseInt(idAndRest[0]);
        String[] nameAndAddress = idAndRest[1].split("\\s*#d\\s*", 2);
        String name = nameAndAddress[0];
        String address = nameAndAddress[1];
        lines.add(new Line(id, name, address));
    }

    public void printLines() {
        for (Line line : lines) {
            System.out.println(line.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Due to your identifier naming, I do not understand your code completely. Thus, I did not use it. Also, I do not want to solve your university task but help you understand how it works.

This code reads the input file line by line. The line splitting is done by the `Files.lines()` method. The parsing of a single line works like this:

- split at `#n`
- before `#n` is the id
- split the part after `#n` at `#d`
- before `#d` is the name
- after `#d` is the address

You might want to do some better error handling here, to ensure that all parts of the line are given and valid. Also, note the second argument of the method `split()`, which is the maximum number of matches, so the resulting arrays do contain at most two entries.

After the parsing, I simply output the resulting list of lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that would work, yes, but I have to use that class. However, I can try to translate everything so maybe you understand it @Stefan Dollase

Answer (score 0):

Well Maria , Stefan has a great answer , I post my example too.
I read the file and keep , first name , last name and address in a list.We can retrieve them later.

```
package StackOverFlow;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
public class readNames{

    String[] word;
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args){
readNames insta=new readNames();
insta.readFile();

}
void readFile(){

    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();


    File file = new File("/home/fotis/Documents/test2.txt");
    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);


        //filePreview.append(sc.nextLine());
        while (sc.hasNext()){
        sc.useDelimiter("\n");
        lines.add(sc.nextLine());
       }

    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Fail to capture the file \n\n\nPlz try Again!! \n\nsorry");
    }
    int len=lines.size();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        String line=lines.get(i);
        //word = line.split("\\s+");
        word=line.split("#n|\\#d");
        names.add(word[1]);
        names.add(word[2]);


    }
    int lent=names.size();
    for(int i=0;i<lent;i++){
        System.out.println(names.get(i));
    }
    }
}
```

The file :
0001 #n Michael Owen #d Liverpool
0002 #n Michael Schumacher #d Munich
0003 #n Michael Jackson #d Heavens
0004 #n Michael Jordan #d Unreachable 6 Chicago
0005 #n Michael Kane #d London

PS:Dont forget to change to the valid file path (your pc , your file)
PS 2:Try it and lets fit it to your class.